# hide old / answered questions I've asked

Tags: feature-request, answered-questions

I already ask a lot of questions and it would be easier to hide answered questions to keep my "to fix" list to a minimum.

It would make the UI of my questions cleaner.

Easy to implement?

Answer (score 2):

I agree. There should be a `Unanswered` or `Open` filter in the profile page so you can filter out the questions that are still open.

Should be very simple to implement (the database already has everything required to make this achievable in a few lines of code).

I'll send an email onto the StackExchange team pointing them to this thread. Hopefully it's something that can be implemented.

Answer (score 2):

There's no convenient button in the UI, and 10 questions isn't that much to go through. Still, you can use the `hasaccepted:0` [search option](https://askubuntu.com/search#advanced-search) to search for [your questions where you haven't marked an answer as accepted](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=user%3A12772+hasaccepted%3A0). The number in the URL after `user:` is your user number, seen in the URL to your profile; it's pre-filled in the search box if you visit your profile. You can also use [`user:me`](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=user%3Ame+hasaccepted%3A0) to mean “posts by me”.

Side note: now that you have more than 15 reputation, you can go and revisit your first questions (or any other question) and [upvote](https://askubuntu.com/privileges/vote-up) answers that you found useful.